# Why does modern graphics with 2Gb memory come with VGA output?

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga, dvi

I recently bought a new computer with a **ATI HD8570 2GB (VGA+HDMI)**. I pay top dollars for a powerful graphics card. I have two (older) monitors from Dell 1600*900 which have a DVI input and a VGA input.

The computer also comes standard with 2 Display Port outputs but I need to use the ones from the graphics card.

After hooking everything up, the quality is lower on the VGA monitor than the HDMI (with converter to DVI). Why does my brand new graphics card come with VGA instead of something more modern? Or am I missing something in the setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mid to high end graphics cards these days *do* come with dual (or more) digital display outputs like DisplayPort, HDMI, and DVI.
The lower end graphics cards still often come with VGA output, as people with lower end graphics cards will also have lower end monitors.

So why does your card have a VGA out..?  Well, I hate to break it to you, but the ATI HD8570 is a lower to mid range OEM card and not worth "top dollar."

Comment: ouch! that hurts..

Comment: @greener If you are going to announce you paid "top dollar" for something, you better do some research to see if its worth it.  The truth can hurt sometimes, but thats how everybody learns.

Comment: I'm reading this thread which is proving very insightful (http://forums.lenovo.com/t5/A-M-and-Edge-Series-ThinkCentre/Question-on-M93p-mini-tower-and-AMD-HD8570-video/td-p/1295999)